# Graalvm Couchbase client not working. How to fix fix?

Tags: netty, quarkus, graalvm, couchbase-java-api

Graalvm native executable not working with couchbase java client. How to fix it ?

Warning: RecomputeFieldValue.ArrayIndexScale automatic substitution failed. The automatic substitution registration was attempted because a call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(Class) was detected in the static initializer of com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.RingBufferFields. Detailed failure reason(s): Could not determine the field where the value produced by the call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(Class) for the array index scale computation is stored. The call is not directly followed by a field store or by a sign extend node followed directly by a field store.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically the work that has to be done while building a Quarkus extension: fixing potential issues with GraalVM by writing GraalVM substitutions.

We don't support Couchbase at the moment. I recommend you to create an extension proposal here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/new?assignees=&labels=extension-proposal&template=extension_proposal.md&title= and see if there are other persons interested to come up with a proper extension.

Comment: Is there any hack solution for this ?